# Split a string on the second empty space after a comma in php (with regex?)

Tags: php, regex, string, split

I'm totally new to regex but I imagine regular expression is the way to solve this:

I have to split with PHP strings containing Italian street addresses.

they are composed like this:

***Street Name, Number ZipCode City***

I need to split it for printing in 2 separate lines like that:

***Street Name, Number***

***ZipCode City***

is it possibile?

Comment: Why did you mark it as "not a real question"?
Is not clear that I'm asking how to split a string with regex? 3 People has asnwered!

Comment: SO is not a *"gimme the codes"* site. If you had made an attempt at regex and posted your attempts asking where you went wrong or why it is not working it would have been a question that would have been fit for SO. You list your criteria and ask if it is possible, simple answer, yes. Just because other people answered does not deem it a correct question to ask as those people apparently do not understand how this site works. If you have any questions on how to ask questions please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: thanks for explanation cryptic, actually my first question was "is it possibile" or "is regex the right way to do that". Sorry but as a total regex newbie I was not sure that a task like that would be performable. Then I was happy to see some people giving me the code, but unfortunately I could not use it because in the end I found out that datas are not consistent as I thought :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_match('/^([^,]+, [^ ]+) (.*)/', $text, $matches);
echo $matches[1] . "\n" . $matches[2];
```

Comment: Whoever's downvoting this, can you provide some sort of feedback on WHY you're downvoting? This response works fine for me.

Comment: actually this code is working even for me.

Answer (score 1):

Give this one a try:

```
preg_match('/^(.+,.+) (.+ .+)$/', $text, $matches);
```

It will place "Street Name, Number" in `$matches[1]` and "ZipCode City" in `$matches[2]`.

Answer (score -1):

Try with `explode()` . Example:

```
$str = 'Street Name, Number ZipCode City';
$ar_str = explode(', ', $str);
$ar2_str = explode(' ', $ar_str[1], 2);
$ar_str[0] .= ', '. $ar2_str[0];

// First needed substring is in $ar_str[0], seccond substring in $ar2_str[1]
// test
echo $ar_str[0] .'<br/>'. $ar2_str[1];
```

Comment: Number must be in the first row

Comment: I noticed, i made other code, hope it helps.